# 3d flow field in R

Tags: r, plot, derivative

I would like to obtain a 3D flow field of system of differential equations in R. The system is in the code.

I've seen that phaseR only support one and two dimensions.

```
 Lorenz<-function(t, state, parameters) {
   with(as.list(c(state, parameters)),{
     # rate of change
     dX <- a*X + Y*Z
     dY <- b * (Y-Z)
     dZ <- -X*Y + c*Y - Z

     # return the rate of change+     list(c(dX, dY, dZ))
     })   # end with(as.list ...
   }
```

I expect a flow field like the one obtained by the function `flowfield()` from the 'phaseR' package or `phaseArrows()` from 'pplane' but in 3D as the systems has 3 variables.

Comment: You've commented out the dX relationship. Is that supposed to mean that all X-values of the vector field will have the same result? And have you looked at `ode.3d` in pkg 'deSolve'?

Comment: @42, thanks I corrected the code. I've seen that ode.3d does a density plot, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The phaseR function only does 2d. My take on that this is really 3 separate problems (or it's a request for a package rec which is off-topic anyway): a) lack of a suitable dataset, b) request for code to generate the data needed for plotting, and c) coding to plot a direction field from a set of points and differentials. So as such it seems you haven't satisfied the requirements for a [MCVE] as a first step, and I'm not even sure that the code you offer has been tested. I guess my closevote is going to be for "too broad", but could also argue for off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The code is proven I have run it and I have the output of the solution for an initial condition which I obtained with ode() from deSolve package. I would like to obtain the flowfield (plot of derivatives of the system in 3D). For that I've looked at the deSolve, phaseR and pplane packages. I'm asking first if there is another package that has a function that does the flowfield for a 3D system.

Comment: Good. Then you have a data object. I explained why your question is not yet in a form where a coding solution is feasible. What parts of my comment that apply to your situation are you having difficulty understanding?